# Orthogonal block-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $$M=\begin{bmatrix}A & C \\ 0 & B\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$$ be a block matrix.

**(a)** If $M$ is orthogonal and $C=0$, are $A$ and $B$ orthogonal?

**(b)** Suppose $A$ is orthogonal and $B=cI$, for some $0<c<1$. Is $M$ orthogonal for any square matrix $C$? (Here $I$ denotes the identity matrix.)

**So far:** It was pretty straight-forward to show that the answer is affirmative in (a), but I am stuck on (b). My gut tells me the answer is no, and I was given a hint to separately check the cases when $C$ is invertible, and when it is not, but I still have a hard time even getting started. I tried to play around with having $A=I$ to make $M$ diagonal, but it didn't help much.

Comment: What do you mean by an orthogonal matrix when $m\ne n$?

Comment: Orthogonal in the sense that $MM^t=I_m$ and $M^tM=I_n$.

Comment: There is no such matrix. $MM^t$ is singular when $m>n$ and $M^tM$ is singular when $m<n$. They cannot be identity matrices at the same time when $m\ne n$.

Comment: I see, then I must have misunderstood, and we only require $MM^t=I_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall an orthogonal matrix is a matrix $M$ where $M^TM=MM^T$. So let's try on your case.

$$M^T=\begin{pmatrix}A^T & 0\\
C^T & B^T\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A^T & 0\\
C^T & cI\end{pmatrix}$$
So we have $$M^TM=\begin{pmatrix}A^T & 0\\
C^T & cI\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A & C\\
0 & cI\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A^TA & AC\\
C^TA & C^TC+c^2I\end{pmatrix}$$
On the other hand, we have
$$MM^T=\begin{pmatrix}A & C\\
0 & cI\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A^T & 0\\
C^T & cI\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}AA^T+CC^T & cC\\
cC^T & c^2I\end{pmatrix}$$

Comparing the entries, we get $C^TC=CC^T=\textbf{O}$. Now we show $C=0$. This is because for any vector $v$, we have $$\left<v,C^TCv\right>=\left<Cv,Cv\right>=\|Cv\|^2=0\implies Cv=0\quad\forall v$$ This must means $C=0$.
So $M=\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\
0 & cI\end{pmatrix}$, which means it has eigenvalue of $c$. But $c$ is in $(0,1)$, and eigenvalue of orthogonal matrix can only be $\pm1$ in real field, so it is impossible for $M$ to be orthogonal.

**Edit:** Thanks for user1551's clarification. This is a serious mistake. I have amended the idea based on the new flow. Sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: What's more, in order for $M$ to be orthogonal, the off diagonal blocks of $MM^T$ and $M^TM$ must be identically zero and the diagonal blocks must be identity. This gives some rather strict conditions for $C$...

Comment: No chance they're equal, thanks.

Comment: I wonder what the hint is supposed to refer to. If you just write out the blocks I don't see a reason to have to consider the invertability of $C$.